# Why is 1 kg of cotton heavier than 1 kg of stone?

Tags: mass, weight

I've been told that 1 kg of cotton has more density since Density = mass / volume, and volume of 1 kg of cotton is pretty big outside , and height of it very long, and stone is lighter because its volume is smaller ? is this right ?

Comment: The cotton has a larger volume and therefore the buoyancy force acting on the cotton will be larger.

Comment: The weight is the same. The density of one kg cotton is smaller.

Comment: If you measure out a quantity of either cotton or stone by weight, what you'll usually measure is its actual mass _minus_ its buoyancy in air anyway. So, if you're using the same weight, one will not be heavier than the other -- _by definition_, since otherwise they wouldn't both measure as 1 kg in the first place!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a block of cotton heavier than a block of iron?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/is-a-block-of-cotton-heavier-than-a-block-of-iron)

Comment: Both have same weight. You only mentioned it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of cotton will be *smaller* than the density of stone, look at your equation $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$. You have $m = 1 \, \mathrm{kg}$ of cotton and $1 \, \mathrm{kg}$ stone, but the cotton takes up more volume, so $V_\text{cotton} > V_\text{stone}$.

(As well, it's wrong to say $1 \, \mathrm{kg}$ of stone is heavier than $1 \, \mathrm{kg}$ of cotton, many people make this mistake, what they usually mean is the density of stone is larger than the density of cotton.)