# Does two objects of the same mass weigh differently in moon and earth if their densities are different?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, density, weight

you have a bag of cotton and an iron bar, each indicating same mass when measured on a weighing machine kept on earth. if you weigh the two objects in moon, which (if any) will weigh higher?

Answer (score 0):

No, both items will weigh the same in both on earth and on the moon (but both items will weigh differently on the earth than on the moon).

Weight is simply mass times the force of gravity.

Comment: You have forgotten about the buoyant force from the atmosphere displaced by the objects.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Hrm. I had not considered that, good point. I don't know what the calculations would be for that, so I'm hesitant to add them to my own answer. Would you like to add a better answer, and I'll delete mine?

Comment: Better answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/153085/10983